# Showing the complement of an open set is closed using sequences

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $U \subseteq X \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$.
>
> A set $U$ is open in $X$ if $X \setminus U$ is closed.

**Definitions**:
(1)  A set $C\subseteq X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed in $X$ if sequences in $C$ cannot converge to points in $X$ that are not in $C$.
(2)  A sequence $x_n$ is said to converge to a point $x$ provided that any given neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains all but finitely many points of $x_n$.

Attempt at a proof:
Suppose to the contrary that $X \setminus U$ is open.  Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of points in $X \setminus U$ that converges to $x \in U$.  Let $N_X(x)$ be a neighborhood of $x$. Then $N_X(x)$ contains all but finitely many points of the sequence $x_n$ and it contains no points of $X\setminus U$.   Hence $U$ is closed.  Contradicting the fact that it is open.

I'm able to prove this using the definitions one would pull out of analysis.  However, it's quite difficult using these definitions.  This is why I am stuck.

Comment: You want to prove : $U$ is open if $X \setminus U$ is closed. So if you use prove by contradiction you should begin with : Assume $X \setminus U$ is closed but $U$ is not open. Thus there is a $u \in U$ s.t. every neigbourhood of $u$ contains a point not in $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subspace can be both open and closed, so your contradiction is not correct. However, you are close to a rigorous proof:

- Suppose by contradiction that $X \backslash U$ is not closed. So there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X \backslash U$ converging to some $x \in U$.
- Because $U$ is open, there exists a neighbohood $V$ of $x$ included into $U$.
- For $n$ large enough, $x_n \in (X \backslash U) \cap V \subset (X \backslash U) \cap U= \emptyset$: a contradiction.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why its for $n$ large enough.  Could I just say the following: let $N_X(x)=\{|y-x|<\epsilon : y \in X\}$.  Then, $N_X(x)$ contains all but finitely many points of $x_n$.  Take $\epsilon=\max\{|x-x_1|,...,|x-x_n|\}$.  The $N_X(x)$ contains points in $X \setminus U$.  A contradiction.

Comment: I just don't follow where your third bullet point comes from.

Comment: When I say that $x_n \in (X \backslash U) \cap U$ for $n$ large enough, I mean that $x_n \in (X \backslash U) \cap U$ for all but finitely many $n$. In your argument, I don't understand the definition of $\epsilon$: how do you choose $n$? In fact, it is because $U$ is open that you can choose $\epsilon$ sufficiently small so that $N_X(x) \subset U$.

Comment: I don't see why its a contradiction.  Because $x \in U$, we know that $U$ contains all but finitely many $n$.  Since $X\setminus U$, it means that $U$ does not share any points of $X \setminus U$>

Comment: I added a detail, is it clearer?

Comment: I understand that the neighborhood will contains all but finitely many.  But I don't understand why that neighborhood might share points with $X \setminus U$.  That is, why $(X\setminus U)\cap V\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Is it just a consequence of both of them being open that they share points?

Comment: They don't share points, you have $(X \backslash U) \cap V= \emptyset$ since $V \subset U$ by assumption.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the contradiction is.  Why is it bad that their intersection is empty?

Comment: $x_n \in V$ because $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and $x_n \in X \backslash U$ by assumption. So $x_n \in (X \backslash U) \cap V$, ie. $(X \backslash U) \cap V \neq \emptyset$. Howerver, because $V \subset U$, $(X \backslash U) \cap V= \emptyset$: a contradiction.

Comment: Ahh ok, so this is saying for large enough $n$, the sequence is in both $X\setminus U$ and $U$?

Comment: Yes, it is what I am saying.